# Pacote bRasilLegis [ comando "obterDetalhesDeputado"]

Tags: r, loop

Estou precisando coletar os dados dos deputados que estiveram presentes em comissões, cargos, etc. Entretanto, só consigo fazer isso com um deputado por vez. É possível que eu possa escolher todos de uma vez?

```
library(bRasilLegis)
dep <- obterDetalhesDeputado(ideCadastro = '81366' , numLegislatura = "55", 
atuacao = "comissoes")
```

O argumento `ideCadastro` é onde eu devo colocar o código do deputado (no caso acima é o '81366'), que é obtido por meio do código `deputados <- obterDeputados()`.

É possível colocar todos os códigos de uma vez?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira coisa a se fazer é obter a lista de deputados, como tu bem colocou no post original:

```
library(bRasilLegis)

deputados <- obterDeputados()
```

Depois disso, é interessante ver o que há dentro do objeto `deputados`. Fazemos isto através do comando `str`. Não vou colocar todo o output dele aqui, porque é um pouco extenso. Vou me ater apenas à primeira coluna do objeto `deputados`:

```
str(deputados)
'data.frame':   511 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ ideCadastro    : chr  "81366" "141522" "195826" "196358" ...
```

Até porque é ela que nos interessa, já que as ids dos deputados estão aí. O que precisamos fazer agora é um loop que mude a id do deputado dentro de cada chamada da função `obterDetalhesDeputado`. Basta fazer um contador `j` assumir todos os valores de `deputados$ideCadastro`.

Também precisamos salvar estes resultados em um lugar. Escolhi salvar numa lista, chamada `dep`.

Por fim, a posição dentro de cada elemento da lista deve variar quando as ids dos deputados variam. Para isto criei um segundo contador chamado `i`, que atualizarei manualmente após baixar as informações de cada deputado.

O código completo fica assim:

```
dep <- list()

i <- 1
for (j in deputados$ideCadastro){
    dep[[i]] <- obterDetalhesDeputado(ideCadastro=j, 
    numLegislatura="55", atuacao="comissoes")
    i <- i+1
}
```

Comment: Marcos, eu usaria um `sapply` ao invés do `for`. Por exemplo `sapply(deputados$ideCadastro, function(j) {...})`. Além de ser mais idiomático, é mais rápido do que sua alternativa, pois ela cresce uma lista, o que é uma operação muito lenta no R, pois a cada alteração a lista é copiada novamente.